# Kubeflow could not be enabled: mutatingwebhookconfigurations.admissionregistration.k8s.io "katib-mutating-webhook-config" not found

Tags: kubeflow, microk8s

I have installed [microk8s](https://microk8s.io/) on Windows using the installer. I have enabled some services with `microk8s enable dashboard dns registry`. But when I try to enable  `kubeflow` I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\biogeek>microk8s enable kubeflow
Enabling dns...
Enabling storage...
Enabling dashboard...
Enabling ingress...
Enabling metallb:10.64.140.43-10.64.140.49...
Waiting for DNS and storage plugins to finish setting up
Deploying Kubeflow...
Kubeflow deployed.
Waiting for operator pods to become ready.
Waited 0s for operator pods to come up, 34 remaining.
Waited 15s for operator pods to come up, 34 remaining.
[...]
Waited 390s for operator pods to come up, 2 remaining.
Operator pods ready.
Waiting for service pods to become ready.
Kubeflow could not be enabled:
Error from server (NotFound): mutatingwebhookconfigurations.admissionregistration.k8s.io "katib-mutating-webhook-config" not found
Error from server (NotFound): validatingwebhookconfigurations.admissionregistration.k8s.io "katib-validating-webhook-config" not found

Command '('microk8s-kubectl.wrapper', 'delete', 'mutatingwebhookconfigurations/katib-mutating-webhook-config', 'validatingwebhookconfigurations/katib-validating-webhook-config')' returned non-zero exit status 1
Failed to enable kubeflow
An error occurred when trying to execute 'sudo microk8s.enable kubeflow' with 'multipass': returned exit code 1.
```

([Error is similar to the one in this Github issue from 2 weeks ago](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/1723), but which hasn't had any response yet.)

Output of `microk8s status --wait-ready`:

```
microk8s is running
addons:
dashboard: enabled
dns: enabled
ingress: enabled
kubeflow: enabled
metallb: enabled
storage: enabled
cilium: disabled
fluentd: disabled
gpu: disabled
helm: disabled
helm3: disabled
istio: disabled
jaeger: disabled
knative: disabled
linkerd: disabled
metrics-server: disabled
prometheus: disabled
rbac: disabled
registry: disabled
```

When I run `microk8s inspect` to [troubleshoot](https://microk8s.io/docs/troubleshooting) the issue, it generates a logfile at `/var/snap/microk8s/1702/...` although I am on Windows!?

```
C:\Users\biogeek>microk8s inspect
Inspecting Certificates
Inspecting services
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-cluster-agent is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-flanneld is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-containerd is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-apiserver is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-apiserver-kicker is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-proxy is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-scheduler is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-controller-manager is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-etcd is running
  Copy service arguments to the final report tarball
Inspecting AppArmor configuration
Gathering system information
  Copy processes list to the final report tarball
  Copy snap list to the final report tarball
  Copy VM name (or none) to the final report tarball
  Copy disk usage information to the final report tarball
  Copy memory usage information to the final report tarball
  Copy server uptime to the final report tarball
  Copy current linux distribution to the final report tarball
  Copy openSSL information to the final report tarball
  Copy network configuration to the final report tarball
Inspecting kubernetes cluster
  Inspect kubernetes cluster

Building the report tarball
  Report tarball is at /var/snap/microk8s/1702/inspection-report-20201123_042132.tar.gz
```

How can I resolve this and successfully install Kubeflow on Windows using Microk8s?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [comment on #1698](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/1698#issuecomment-731260701), a fix for this issue is included in microk8s `1.20/stable`.

```
sudo snap install microk8s --classic --channel=1.20/edge
```